# Does Genesis 3 suggest that Adam and Eve's fig-leaf loincloths (v. 7) were unable to cover nakedness, unlike the tunics of skin (v. 21)?

Tags: genesis, hebrew, word-study

In Genesis 3:6-10, the first recorded effect of Adam and Eve's sin is that they realized they were naked. Because of this, they sewed fig leaves together to make loincloths, but this isn't considered enough, as their dialogue with God reveals they were still naked. Instead, in Genesis 3:21, God made them tunics of skin.

While there are many contrasts that can be drawn between the fig-leaf loincloths and the tunics of skin, does the text suggest that the fig leaves were unable to cover nakedness (since it still suggests Adam and Eve were naked)? Thanks!

Comment: The point is not the _extent_ of coverage. The symbolism is in the _type_ of containment. They were clothed in the skin of another. They needed another humanity.

Comment: @NigelJ In the verses cited, isn't the problem that they were "naked" (i.e., not sufficiently clothed)? If so, then there's something about the tunic that resolves this problem in a way that the fig leaves did not, correct?

Answer (score 3):

Dottard's answer is excellent. But I would like to add a few things.

The Hebrew word for tunic is ketonet כְּתֹנֶת. It is only used for Adam and Eve's coats of skins, Joseph's coat of many colours, Tamar's coat of many colours and finally tunics of fine linen for Aaron and his sons (Levitical priests). So we can already see some priestly allusions. Adam and Eve supposed to be a kingdom of priests in Eden.

Adam and Eve's nakedness before sin although neutral suggests incompleteness. I believe that they were going to be clothed by God with robes of "light". Transfigured Christ (Matthew 17, Mark 9, Luke 9; Revelation 1) as well as angels always wear radiant white robes. As if made of light. That is what the white linen tunics of a priests pointed to.

I also link Isaiah 61:10 (garments of salvation (yesha/Yeshua) with Romans 13:14, Galatians 3:27 & Colossians 10.

Additionally, there is an interesting word play. Light in Hebrew is אוֹר. Skin in Hebrew is עוֹר. Both words are pronounced the same. Or. So although tunics of skins and tunics of light sound the same, they are two different things and symbolize two different realities. Instead of putting the tunic of light/righteousness, Adam was clothed in the tunic of skins. Which was still a great promise of hope. Because what was lost in Adam is fully restored in Jesus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you agree that 1) a problem was nakedness as in not having enough clothing, that 2) the fig leaves did not stop the nakedness, and that 3) the tunics of skin did?

Comment: Yes. But symbolically the tunic of skin just like the law was meant  to be temporary.

Answer (score 2):

The fig leaves vs the tunics made of animal skin for Adam and Eve, is the same matter as with Cain's offering of vegetable and fruit vs the sacrificial lamb, Gen 4.

Adam and Eve's coverings for their nakedness were man-made; the tunics of animal skin, given by God, meant that some sacrificial animal had died to provide a covering in their sinful state.

This is alluded to again in other places, especially in Isaiah:

- Isa 64:6 - Each of us has become like something unclean, and all our righteous acts are like **filthy rags**; we all wither like a leaf, and our iniquities carry us away like the wind.  [Cloth/rag is made of cotton or some other plant fiber.]
- Isa 61:10 - I will rejoice greatly in the LORD, my soul will exult in my God; for He has clothed me with **garments of salvation** and wrapped me in a **robe of righteousness**, as a bridegroom wears a priestly headdress, as a bride adorns herself with her jewels.

Rev 19:8 appears to allude to Isaiah - a robe of righteousness from God given to the bride of the Lamb.

Comment: Excellent answer. You have made very good connections. But I think that it goes deeper than this. Check my answer and let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you agree that 1) a problem was nakedness, 2) the fig leaves did not stop the nakedness, and 3) the tunics of skin did?

Comment: @ארקדיוס - I liked your answer but it suffers from the shortcoming of being by inference rather that simple comparison.  That is not to suggest it is wrong - I think both are correct.

Comment: @TheEditor - both garments cover nakedness but the skin was (a) given by God and (b) involved a sacrificial animal and so were a reminder of the coming Messiah.  The fig leaves were man-made and therefore represented man's attempt at righteousness.

Comment: @Dottard I think those points are worthy of consideration. There are a lot of contrasts. Regarding the covering of nakedness, would 3:10-11 suggest that they were naked even after making the fig-leaf loincloths?

Comment: @TheEditor - they were NOT naked after the fig-leaves but the fig-leaves were not suitable coverings for the above reasons.

Comment: @Dottard In 3:7, they realized that they were naked and made coverings from fig leaves. In the very next verse, 3:8, they hid from the LORD. "Why?" God asks in 3:9. According to Adam in 3:10, it's because he was _still naked_. Notice that this is _after_, not before, verse 7, where they make the fig-leaf coverings. If they were _not_ naked after the fig leaves, then why did Adam say his hiding _after_ the fig leaves was due to being naked? Doesn't it appear that "naked" in this verse means lacking _sufficient_ clothing rather than lacking _all_ clothing, appropriateness requiring tunics?

Comment: @TheEditor - the hiding was because of the shame of sin of eating the fruit - it case the realization of nakedness and the fear of God.  The same thing occurs in Rev 6:15-17 where the wicked fear the presence of God and seek destruction.  Note God's first question - did you eat of the fruit?

Comment: @Dottard According to Adam, "...I was afraid **because I was naked**; and I hid myself" (Gen. 3:10, NKJV). God's first question afterward isn't about the fruit but, "Who told you that you were naked?" God then asks if this means they ate the fruit. In other words, they realized they were naked and made coverings (3:7), then hid (3:8), then were asked where they were (3:9). Then, Adam says it's because he was naked that he hid (3:10), causing God to ask if they therefore ate the fruit (3:11). Doesn't Adam directly say that it was "because [he] was naked" that he became afraid and hid himself?

Comment: @TheEditor - the problem is the spiritual sin - it is NOT just physical, unless you insist upon just seeing the words - look at what they are saying - they covered themselves and still felt ashamed!  Unless you want to make covered still naked?  The naked refers to the fact that they needed a covering at all and were ashamed - they should not have needed any covering.

Answer (score 1):

When God made Adam and Eve, He made them in His image.  Throughout the Bible, that "image" is represented as being His perfect character, and the skin or its covering is a symbol of character.

For example, God says:

> Can the Ethiopian change his skin, or the leopard his spots? then may
> ye also do good, that are accustomed to do evil. (Jeremiah 13:23, KJV)

This likens one's character to his skin.  And in Revelation we also are given instructions to "wash our robes."

> And I said unto him, Sir, thou knowest. And he said to me, These are
> they which came out of great tribulation, and have washed their robes,
> and made them white in the blood of the Lamb. (Revelation 7:14, KJV)

The sacrificial animals brought to the temple were not to have any blemish in their skin because they were to represent Jesus whose character was perfect and sinless just as the characters of Adam and Eve were sinless and perfect when they were created in God's image.

And how is God clothed?

> Who coverest [thyself] with light as with a garment: who stretchest
> out the heavens like a curtain: (Psalm 104:2, KJV)

*[Note that the word "thyself" is supplied in the KJV and, if removed, could also apply to God's creation.]*

God had created Adam and Eve in His likeness.  As God was covered in a robe of light, so were they.  But they lost this when they sinned.  That is when they noticed that they were naked.  They also felt a sense of chilliness which they hadn't noticed before.

> And they heard the voice of the LORD God walking in the garden **in the
> cool of the day:** and Adam and his wife hid themselves from the
> presence of the LORD God amongst the trees of the garden. (Genesis
> 3:8, KJV)

How well would fig leaves, or any green leaves for that matter, protect against the chill of the evening?  Not very well, to be sure.  God knew they needed something more.

> Unto Adam also and to his wife did the LORD God make coats of skins,
> and clothed them. (Genesis 3:21, KJV)

More than this, the leaves, as compared to the garments of skins, could not represent the remedy for the sin which had brought them into this need.  The leaves, being purely of plant origin and without blood, could no more represent the sacrifice and cost to God that their sin had caused than could Cain's offering atone for his sin.

> And almost all things are by the law purged with blood; and without
> shedding of blood is no remission. (Hebrews 9:22, KJV)

The coats of skins which God made for the guilty pair cost the life of some animal(s).  It was a lesson to both of them in how much their sin would cost.  This lesson would have been entirely absent had the fig-leaf covering been sufficient to cover their shame.

So, both for physical warmth and protection, and for the spiritual lessons embodied in the representations made of them, there was a wide difference between the fig-leaf coverings Adam and Eve had made for themselves and the coverings of skin which God made for them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you agree that 1) a problem was nakedness, 2) the fig leaves did not stop the nakedness, and 3) the tunics of skin did?

Answer (score 1):

Dottard's comment stated the profound significance behind Adam's sense of nakedness when he conversing with the Lord (Genesis 3:10). It stemmed from his profound shame of disobedience and his profound fear of God. Consequently **this state of nakedness symbolises a spiritual condition wherein no transgression can remain hidden before God.**

It is only through divine forgiveness that our sins can be absolved, a concept symbolised by the garments provided by God to cloth Adam and Eve (Genesis 3:21). The garments, fashioned from animal skins, symbolised a sacrifice is require to obtain pardon for sin. This foreshadows the Lord would sacrifice His Son who would bear the sins of the world. While Genesis does not specific the source of these animal skins, by the nature we know afterward, it could possibly involve a lamb.

> The next day John saw Jesus coming toward him and said, **“Look, the Lamb of God, who takes away the sin of the world!** (John 1:29 NIV)

King David wrote in his Psalm 32

> Blessed is the one whose transgressions are forgiven,
> **whose sins are covered**. (Psalm 32:1 NIV)

Another implication from this account is, one must be aware of his nakedness in order to plead the Lord a cover, that is, aware of our sins and asked for forgiveness. Otherwise, just as Jesus answered the Pharisees;

> 31 Jesus answered them, “**It is not the healthy who need a doctor, but the sick.**
>
> 32 I have not come to call the righteous, but sinners to repentance.” (Luke 5:31-32 NIV)

Regarding to the OP's question **"Were the fig-leaf loincloths unable to cover nakedness, unlike the tunics of skin (v.21)?**

The answer is "yes" in its implication. For the fig-leaf loincloths were made by themselves, that implied salvation cannot be achieved by own's work.

Answer (score 0):

God commanded Adam in Genesis 2:

> 17 but you must not eat from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, for when you eat from it you will certainly **die**.”

Despite this warning, Adam and Eve disobeyed in Genesis 3:

> 6 When the woman saw that the fruit of the tree was good for food and pleasing to the eye, and also desirable for gaining wisdom, she took some and ate it. She also gave some to her husband, who was with her, and he ate it.

Now they would learn about the consequences of sin and dying. To attempt to cover their shame/sin,

> 7 Then the eyes of both of them were opened, and they realized they were naked; so they sewed fig leaves together and made coverings for themselves.

In the eyes of God, this was not enough to cover their sin.

> 21 The Lord God made garments of **skin** for Adam and his wife and clothed them.

Someone or some animal had to die; blood had to be shed to cover sin.

Leviticus 7:

> 8
> The priest who offers a burnt offering for anyone may keep its hide for himself.

What would the tunics of skin have covered that the loincloths would not? Did the fig leaves only cover their waist whereas the tunics covered shoulders to knees, perhaps?

It might be true that the animal skin had provided more coverage than the fig leaves. However, the point wasn't which garment provided more outward coverage on their bodies. The point had to do with inner shame and sin.
Fig leaves only provided a superficial covering. God wanted to deal with the deeper issue of a guilty conscience. Blood had to be shed. Vicarious death had to happen. Adam and Eve had to learn the lesson of disobeying God.

In Genesis 3, what's the difference between the fig-leaf loincloths (v. 7) and tunics of skin (v. 21)?

Fig-leaf was man's attempt to cover shame/sin. God's way needed blood and vicarious death.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, while the big point would be the animal skins, would you agree that 1) a problem was nakedness as in not having enough clothing, that 2) the fig leaves did not stop the nakedness, and that 3) the tunics of skin did?

Comment: Agreed. I accommodate both the horizontal (physical) reasons as well as the vertical (spiritual) reasons whenever they make sense to do so. This is the beauty of Co-Reality Hermeneutics.

Comment: I see. There are a lot of angles from which to view the contrast in clothing.

Answer (score 0):

Fig leafs, of all possibilities, seems an odd choice for garment material and therefore probably not random in symbolism or allegory.  Fig leafs are listed as a skin irritant containing furocoumarins and ficin. Itching burning etc. The idea of use as underwear material might seem almost comedic in contact with such sensitive areas of skin!

I posit this effect would have been known to the writers and is purposefully included. Fig leaves were man's choice, animal skins were God's. It seems a reasonable consideration whether this 'mistake' could rather be an early illustration of the effect of removal of God's protective hand.

Comment: Welcome to BH and thanks for you contribution.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. I recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Thank you - removed and rephrased a rhetorical question.